# Cannot resolve method 'setAdapter()'

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have found several questions similar to this one, but none of them fix my issue. Here is the code I have written -

```
DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
ListView notesList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper (this);
    notesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notesList);
    loadNotesList ();
}

public void loadNotesList () {
    ArrayList<String> notesList = dataBaseHelper.getNameList();
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.note_name, notesList);
        notesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(notesList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

...
```

My code *seems* just like the code in the tutorial I was following, and my code *seems* like it is in the correct place, but I know that I am missing something or did something wrong, because Android Studio gives me this error-

`Cannot resolve method 'setAdapter(android.widget.ArrayAdapter<java.lang.String>)'`

Does anybody see what I did wrong, or what I might need to add or change? Thank you!

Comment: Well, an `ArrayList` does not have a `setAdapter(String)` method and `notesList` is an `ArrayList`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have introduced local variable `notesList` inside `loadNotesList` function:

```
ArrayList<String> notesList = dataBaseHelper.getNameList();
```

Change this name to something else.

Comment: This answered my question *exactly*. I just had conflicting variables, and that's all. Thank you, my man.

Comment: @GeorgeB Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a `ListView` as the last parameter of

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.note_name, notesList);
```

That's not valid.

Comment: Yes. That's because I have conflicting variables `ListView notesList` and `ArrayList<String> notesList = dataBaseHelper.getNameList()`. I just changed one of the variables, and it works now.

Comment: You're very welcome. Just accept the answer, so other devs can benefit from your question.

Comment: @GeorgeB It's not true. He passes ArrayList<String> as the last parameter, not ListView. Look carefully, he introduces local variable notesList.

Answer (score 1):

`notesList` is a ArrayList of strings and a ListView, you will need to change the name.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a `member` variable `notesList` for `ListView`

```
ListView notesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notesList);
```

and another on is `ArrayList` of `string` which is a `local` variable of method `loadNotesList()`

```
ArrayList<String> notesList = dataBaseHelper.getNameList();
```

**SOLUTION:**

You can use `this` operator or use different name for 2 variables.

**Try this:**

```
DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
ArrayList<String> notesList

ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper (this);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notesList);
    loadNotesList ();
}

public void loadNotesList () {
    notesList = dataBaseHelper.getNameList();

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.note_name, notesList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(notesList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your have declared `ListView notesList;` outside the method(member variable)  and the `ArrayList<String> notesList` is inside the `loadNotesList()`(locale variable).

So when you trying to access `notesList` inside the method, Locale variable will call([Scope of variables](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm)).

As a solution you can add `this.notesList`(`this` keyword to refer to instance/member variable in the class), like below:

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.note_name, this.notesList);//will call member variable
```

however, to keep simplicity, you can rename one of the `notesList` variable name(up to you).